# How to convert TINYINT(1) to BOOLEAN in express?

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, boolean, tinyint

I have some columns (`infected` and `absence`) in my MySQL database that are stored as `TINYINT(1)`.

When I do a simple

```
app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
  const sql = `SELECT * from users`;
  connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.send(err);
    } else {
      return res.json({ results });
    }
  });
});
```

in my backend and a

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`${config.server}/users`)
      .then((result) => {
        setUsers(result.data.results);
      })
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }, [setUsers]);
```

in my ReactJS frontend, I am not able to do something like:

```
users.filter((u) => u.infected);
```

Only

```
users.filter((u) => u.infected === 1);
```

is working.

As using `users.filter((u) => u.infected);` is more intuitive for me, I want to know, how can I handle this in best practice?

1. Do I need to store my values in another type?
2. Do I need to SELECT the values in a different way?
3. Do I need to translate the values from 1 to TRUE and 0 to FALSE after querying them?
4. Do I need to translate the values in the frontend after the get request?

I try to avoid using 4. unless this is not the best deal, because my frontend already expects booleans all over the place (I switched the database to MySQL).

Comment: "I am not able to do something like:" --- why? What does "am not able" exactly mean?

Comment: I don't know? It's not working - only `=== 1` is working. Maybe this is because `typeof u.infected` is a number?

Comment: Can you show `console.log(JSON.stringify(u.infected))` for both positive and negative values?

Comment: It's logging `0` and `1`

Comment: It cannot log `0` and `1`, are there quotes around? Can you copy the **exact unmodified** output. Because if there are literally `0` and `1` values then `users.filter((u) => u.infected)` would have worked.

Comment: I receive `1 1 string number false` for `console.log(JSON.stringify(infected),infected,typeof JSON.stringify(infected),typeof infected,JSON.stringify(infected) === infected);`

Comment: and for the non 1 row?

Comment: I get `0 0 string number false`

Comment: Given they are numbers and are either `0` or `1` - `users.filter((u) => u.infected)` would work. If the behaviour is still not what you expect - then the **actual data** is not what you think it is and you should provide some code that actually demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `!!` they will convert the value to a boolean type.
It's equivalent with: `Boolean(anyValue)`.

`users.filter(u => !!u.infected);`